# Contacting tech support

Tags: discussion

Should we expect that the users have tried to contact tech support when available? If not, should we recommend they try that before doing anything that might void their warranty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should we expect that the users have tried to contact tech support when available?

No.  A good chunk of users come to the internet because it's easier than getting tech support.

> If not, should we recommend they try that before doing anything that might void their warranty?

Up to you.  It normally wouldn't be appropriate to provide an answer saying only to contact tech support, but it would be fine as a comment — assuming that it seems to you like something best handled by tech support.

Comment: Thanks. I had the feeling most people wouldn't have tried tech support, but I was wondering whether I should tell others to.